# Extract names from File_B having overlapping intervals with File_A

Tags: text-processing, awk

Two space-delimited files:

File_A

```
MT 50000
groupI 7850000
groupI 7950000
groupI 9050000
groupI 21750000
groupII 8750000
groupII 10550000
groupII 16150000
groupII 20850000
groupIII 14750000
groupIII 15250000
groupIII 15450000
groupIII 15550000
groupIII 15650000
groupIV 7850000
```

The first column is the group ID and **the second column is the mid-point of an interval 100,000 units long** within the group. For example the first row corresponds to the interval 1-100000 in group MT, the second row the interval 7800000-7900000, and so on.

File_B

```
MT 2851 3825 Name=mt-nd1
MT 4036 5082 Name=mt-nd2
MT 5465 7015 Name=mt-co1
MT 7173 7863 Name=mt-co2
MT 8097 8780 Name=mt-atp6
groupI 18791 22890 Name=FGF12
groupI 36880 38991 Name=MB21D2
groupI 65279 68049 Name=cldn15lb
groupI 77722 105198 Name=col4a4
groupI 117583 141390 Name=col4a3
groupI 150455 155401 Name=sst1.1
groupI 9050030 9058000 Name=bco2b
groupI 1076088 1085084 Name=SORL1
groupI 1175505 1181937 Name=abcg4b
groupI 1184288 1184688 Name=lyrm9
groupI 1185206 1186192 Name=ift20
```

Column 1 of File_B is the group/chromosome name where a gene is located, column 2 and 3 are the intervals of a gene, where column 2 is the start and column 3 is the end. Finally, column 4 is the gene name.
I want to extract the only gene names from the 4th column of File_B that whose interval fall within the 100,000 interval of File_A.

Output_file

```
mt-nd1
mt-nd2
mt-co1
mt-co2
mt-atp6
bco2b
```

I was using the following code for a different, although similar, procedure (File_B had more columns and the second column for File_A was a point not an interval).

```
while read -r id pos; do awk -v id="$id" -v pos="$pos" '$1 == id && pos > $4 && pos < $5 { if (gensub(/.*gene=([A-Za-z0-9]*).*/, "\\1", 1) !~ /\s/) print gensub(/.*gene=([A-Za-z0-9]*).*/, "\\1", 1); }' <File_B.txt; done < File_A.txt > Output_file.txt
```

Comment: Hello @Age87 not clear how the output was generated would you please add more clarifications?Would you please explain  for example why `mt-nd1` is an output?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the group name has to be the same (it's not clear from your description, but the data and the expected output suggest so):

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2n,2n <(awk '{print $1, $2-50000, $2+50000, $2}' File_A) File_B |
  awk '
    !gsub(/[^=]*=/, "", $4) {g=$1; s=$2; e=$3; m=$4; next}
    $2 > s && $3 <= e && $1 == g {if(m){print g, m; m=""} print "   "$4}
  '
MT 50000
   mt-nd1
   mt-nd2
   mt-co1
   mt-co2
   mt-atp6
groupI 9050000
   bco2b
```

Without headings:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2n,2n <(awk '{print $1, $2-50000, $2+50000}' File_A) File_B |
  awk '
    !gsub(/[^=]*=/, "", $4) {g=$1; s=$2; e=$3; next}
    $2 > s && $3 <= e && $1 == g {print $4}
  '
mt-nd1
mt-nd2
mt-co1
mt-co2
mt-atp6
bco2b
```

Comment: Perfect!  Yes, you guessed right, I did want the first columns to match for a given interval.