# Extracting names from file_a using information from 2 columns in file_b

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed

Building on: [Extract names from File_B having overlapping intervals with File_A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475491/extract-names-from-file-b-having-overlapping-intervals-with-file-a)

I want to extract gene names (usually column 10, what's after "Name=") by matching the first column of file_b to file_a, and extracting the gene names if the second column of file_b lies within the gene interval, delineated by columns 4 and 5 of file_b. The first columns must match, such that I only get one gene per row (file_b) but I could in theory have multiple adjacent rows (column_b) match the same gene (e.g. if the second row in file_b was `MT 4065`)

There are a few problems with the code I have now.

(1)the way it is set up below, the last row of file_b is lost from the output, although this changes if this row (`groupVII    17978350`) is brought up the list. I would like it to work the way it is set up.

(2)The names are truncated if they have special characters (eg colons and hyphens). I would like to have the entire name after the equal sign.

(3) I would like to match the entry/row of file_b to the gene hits in the output, such that the first two columns is the entry and the third column is the gene hit.

file_a.tsv

```
MT  insdc   gene    2851    3825    .   +   .   ID=gene:ENSGACG00000020925  Name=mt-nd1 biotype=protein_coding  description=NADH dehydrogenase 1%2C mitochondrial [Source:ZFIN%3BAcc:ZDB-GENE-011205-7] gene_id=ENSGACG00000020925  logic_name=mt_genbank_import    version=1
MT  insdc   gene    4036    5082    .   +   .   ID=gene:ENSGACG00000020929  Name=mt-nd2 biotype=protein_coding  description=NADH dehydrogenase 2%2C mitochondrial [Source:ZFIN%3BAcc:ZDB-GENE-011205-8] gene_id=ENSGACG00000020929  logic_name=mt_genbank_import    version=1
groupIII    ensembl gene    7332324 7334769 .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSGACG00000015265  Name=si:dkeyp-68b7.10   biotype=protein_coding  description=si:dkeyp-68b7.10 [Source:ZFIN%3BAcc:ZDB-GENE-070912-667]    gene_id=ENSGACG00000015265  logic_name=ensembl  version=1
groupIV ensembl gene    1368026 1374881 .   +   .   ID=gene:ENSGACG00000016447  Name=hnrnpa0b   biotype=protein_coding  description=heterogeneous nuclear ribonucleoprotein A0b [Source:ZFIN%3BAcc:ZDB-GENE-030131-6154]    gene_id=ENSGACG00000016447  logic_name=ensembl  version=1
groupIV ensembl gene    5347339 5349041 .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSGACG00000017010  Name=zgc:153018 biotype=protein_coding  description=zgc:153018 [Source:ZFIN%3BAcc:ZDB-GENE-060929-752]  gene_id=ENSGACG00000017010  logic_name=ensembl  version=1
groupV  ensembl gene    120615  125489  .   +   .   ID=gene:ENSGACG00000002103  Name=zdhhc6 biotype=protein_coding  description=zinc finger%2C DHHC-type containing 6 [Source:ZFIN%3BAcc:ZDB-GENE-030131-3189]  gene_id=ENSGACG00000002103  logic_name=ensembl  version=1
groupVI ensembl gene    11230354    11232784    .   +   .   ID=gene:ENSGACG00000009527  Name=bnip4  biotype=protein_coding  description=BCL2 interacting protein 4 [Source:ZFIN%3BAcc:ZDB-GENE-051113-212]  gene_id=ENSGACG00000009527  logic_name=ensembl  version=1
groupVII    ensembl gene    2271611 2277214 .   +   .   ID=gene:ENSGACG00000019012  Name=sf3b2  biotype=protein_coding  description=splicing factor 3b%2C subunit 2 [Source:ZFIN%3BAcc:ZDB-GENE-070928-1]   gene_id=ENSGACG00000019012  logic_name=ensembl  version=2
groupVII    ensembl gene    15815857    15824549    .   +   .   ID=gene:ENSGACG00000020296  Name=mpp1   biotype=protein_coding  description=membrane protein%2C palmitoylated 1 [Source:ZFIN%3BAcc:ZDB-GENE-031113-4]   gene_id=ENSGACG00000020296  logic_name=ensembl  version=1
groupVII    ensembl gene    17978322    17982388    .   +   .   ID=gene:ENSGACG00000020399  Name=si:ch211-284e13.4  biotype=protein_coding  description=si:ch211-284e13.4 [Source:ZFIN%3BAcc:ZDB-GENE-060526-161]   gene_id=ENSGACG00000020399  logic_name=ensembl  version=1
```

file_b.tsv

```
MT  4050
groupIII    7332350
groupIV 5347350
groupVI 11230375
groupVII    17978350
```

code:

```
while read -r id pos; do awk -v id="$id" -v pos="$pos" '$1 == id && pos > $4 && pos < $5 { if (gensub(/.*Name=([A-Za-z0-9]*).*/, "\\1", 1) !~ /\s/) print gensub(/.*Name=([A-Za-z0-9]*).*/, "\\1", 1); }' <file_a.tsv; done < file_b.tsv > output.tsv
```

output.tsv

```
mt
si
zgc
bnip4
```

Desired_output

```
MT  4050    mt-nd2
groupIII    7332350 si:dkeyp-68b7.10
groupIV 5347350 zgc:153018
groupVI 11230375    bnip4
groupVII    17978350    si:ch211-284e13.4
```

Comment: You need to insert `\t` between fields in your `output.tsv` file. Otherwise, it's not a `tsv` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# save this as script.awk or whatevernameyouwant.awk

function within_range(val, lower, upper, proximity) {
    # you can specify the "proximity" as required
    return val > lower - proximity && val < upper + proximity
}

BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
}

$1 == id && within_range(pos, $4, $5, 100) {
    name = gensub(/.*Name=([^\t]*).*/, "\\1", 1)
    if (name ~ /[^[:space:]]+/)
        print id, pos, name
}
```

Then run

```
while read -r id pos
do
    awk -v id=$id -v pos=$pos -f script.awk file_a.tsv
done < file_b.tsv > output.tsv
```

**Please** make sure that the fields in your `.tsv` files are separated by tabs before processing them. My output:

```
MT  4050    mt-nd2
groupIII    7332350 si:dkeyp-68b7.10
groupIV 5347350 zgc:153018
groupVI 11230375    bnip4
groupVII    17978350    si:ch211-284e13.4
```

For the ID `MT`, the gene hit should be `mt-nd2` not `mt-nd1`.

I still recommend using Python for data processing.

Comment: I noticed a bigger problem. The code is not requiring that the first column of file_b match the first column of file_a, so I am getting spurious hits when the second column of file_b falls within an interval, regardless if the first columns match. For example, I may get two gene names for MT 4050, if 4050 falls within a different interval, say of groupIII. Anyway around this? I uploaded the larger files here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eh7jnmdevi3kmeb/AABPfR3SaciRJapZhdiVXOtha?dl=0   thanks again

Comment: I've just tested it by adding a spurious copy of the same MT row in file_a.tsv with the same interval from 4036 to 5082, but with the id changed to something else (I changed it to FOO). My code didn't match that spurious row. The `$1 ~ id` check worked for me.

Comment: Try changing `$1 ~ id` to `$1 == id`. See if that fixes your problem. Yeah, that could explain why you got false matches. I should have used `$1 == id`. I've edited my code.

Comment: Perfect! You were right,changing it to $1 == id worked. Thank you. And learning some Python is definitely on my list ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your expected shown output doesn't look to me consistent(2 lines-->1st and 3rd), if that is a typo then could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a) && (a[$1]>=$4 && a[$1]<=$5){sub("Name=","",$10);print $1,a[$1],$10}'  b.tsv a.tsv > output.tsv
```

Comment: @Age87, cool, you could EDIT my answer so that other people may learn from it and try to select any answer as correct one out of all.

Comment: @Sin15, yes, I will take a look to it after sometime.